# MySQL/PHP mass delete using array: Best method?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to do a mass delete from a MySQL table via PHP (using PDO).  The table has a field called 'id' and all the id's to be deleted are stored in an array.  There may be 5 rows to delete from the table or there may be 5000+.

My immediate thought is to use a foreach and iterate through the array deleting one at time.  However something tells me that may not be a very good method if there are a lot of elements in the array.

Any thoughts on a best method for doing this type of delete?

Comment: Use `IN`: `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: @mcryan is right. But, honestly, iterating over 5,000 array elements containing SQL record ids for a SQL Delete command isn't really detrimental to performance, unless you plan to integrate the process into a public user interface on a high-traffic domain.  Basically, it might take 10 seconds for you.  Which isn't a bad thing.  It's bad when a user waits 10 seconds.  You can also iterate over your array and build a query string.  In some cases, using a where clause with OR is better for performance than using IN.  If performance matters, test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following query replacing `table_name` with the name of the table. `$listofIdsToDelete` is the the comma separated string obtained by exploding the array of ids'

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE id IN ($listofIdsToDelete)";
```

**EDIT:**

You will get a better performance if you prepare:

```
$pQuery = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ?"
```

and bind each id item in the loop and execute .

Thanks to UselessIntern for the correction mentioned below and the suggestion to include this comment in the answer

Comment: It's an array use implode(',' , $listofIdsToDelete) instead.

Comment: You will get a better performance if you prepare $pQuery = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ?" and bind each item in the array

Comment: Ah so add that tidbit of information to your answer. It's not clear, to me at least, at a glance.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know about IN and I wondered if there was prepared statement way of doing it...will look into that.

Answer (score 2):

use `WHERE IN`:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,5,6,7);
$db->exec('DELETE from table WHERE id IN ?', [implode(',' $ids)]);
```